# OpenGL ES 2.0: What is the link between projection matrix and aspect ratio?

Tags: android, opengl-es

**Problem:**
I am reading "OpenGL ES 2 for Android:A Quick-Start Guide" and got to chapter 5 where they start taking the devices' aspect ratio into consideration and **I can't seem to understand the link that they make between the orthographic projection and a devices aspect ratio.** In the book they mention the use of an orthographic projection that will allow one to step out of the normalized coordinate space that OpenGL uses and into a virtual coordinate space to be able to account for the aspect ratio. Then they state once the aspect ratio has been considered you have to take the virtual coordinates back into the normalized system. **I was bit confused as to their use of the words "virtual coordinate system" here as well**.

**What I comprehend:**
I understand that if you were to make a circle and placed it in OpenGL's normalized coordinate system the circle would get stretched and squished depending on the orientation of the device because a device has a different aspect ratio than the aspect ratio of 1 that the normalized coordinate system of OpenGL has. What I don't understand is how using an Orthographic projection will help us solve the issue. I think I understand what an Orthographic projection is but in case I don't can someone define this in simple terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I understand what an Orthographic projection is but in case I don't can someone define this in simple terms?

I think this is part of the problem. You understand the term *projection* in the mathematical sense - an idempotent mapping, which is typical when reducing the dimensionality of your data. In a typical render pipeline, the "projection" matrix doesn't do any projection at all. Instead, the rendering API defines some conventions for a 3D *view* *volume*. In OpenGL, the viewing volume is defined as the cube `-1 <= x,y,z <= 1` in normalized device coordinates. The sides of each cube form the six clip planes. Any geometry outside these will be clipped or culled - so these planes simply represent the edges of the screen (or actually, the viewport, but imagine the screen here is more intuitive).

The task of the projection matrix (in combination of the perspective divide by `w`) is to just transform from 3D eye space (some cartesian coordinate system relative to the "camera", if one wants to think in those terms) to 3D normalized device space. There is no mathematical projection happening in the normal case. This also means that **the projection matrix defines the position of the 6 clipping planes in eye space**. You can basically just take the well-defined corners of the view volume in normalized device space, and apply the inverse of the projection matrix (and do another perspective divide) and get back the eight corners of the viewing volume in eye space.
As a result, the projection matrix defines which extent of the world is mapped to the screen, and the aspect ratio of the viewing frustum must equal the aspect ratio of the viewport used for rendering if the object shall appear undistorted.

For a orthographic "projection", all what the projection matrix does is defining some cuboid in eye space (usually an axis-aligned one, so it boils down to scale and a translation per dimension). Typically, such ortho transformation is defined by directly specifying the viewing volume in eye space, i.e. specifying the `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` and `near` and `far` values. The projection matrix now simply maps `x_eye=left` to -1 (the left clipping plane in NDC), and `x_eye=right` to 1 (the right clipping plane in NDC), and so on.

In case of a perspective "projection", the viewing volume will be a *pyramid frustum* in eye space. The math for that is a bit more complicated as we have to play with the homogenuous `w` component, and I don't want to go into details here, but the key point I'm trying to get through here is that there still is no projection. A perspective projection transforms the pyramid view frustum into a cube in NDC, and it  transforms everything inside of this volume with it - a cube in the view frustum will actually by deformed to a somewhat "inverted" pyramid frustum, where the farther away parts *actually* get smaller in NDC.

The only case where the real *projection* is happening is during rasterization when only the `x` and `y` coordiantes are considered - and this is always an orthographic projection along `z`m and it is not done by any proejction matrix.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer because I know this tells me exactly what I need although I am still having trouble grasping the concept fully. I just need time to really dissect what you wrote. I think I'm overthinking it. Thank you nonetheless! Very informative reply.